# I am unable to compile makefile. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Tags: command-line, make, makefile

I am still a begginer at using Ubuntu. I've been trying to run a makefile with some .sv and .ys codes containing simple verilog and yosys exaples.

The makefile contains:

```
SYNTH = yosys

rtl: 
    ${SYNTH} -s run.ys
```

When typing `$./makefile` into ubuntu terminal all I get in return is:

```
./makefile: line 1: SYNTH: command not found
./makefile: line 3: rtl:: command not found
./makefile: line 4: -s: command not found
```

When I simply run `$yosys -s run.ys` everything works perfectly. The problem also remains for other similar or more complex examples of code and makefiles.

Comment: You don't run the `makefile` itself.  You just type in `make` and it should read the make file and start to compile, if the contents of the make file are correct.